# Shutdown /a doesn't work... error

Tags: windows-7, windows, shutdown

I had a bat file with `shutdown -a` for when I accidentally shut down pc bit it gave me this error when I had the chance to use it (i.e. after shutdown had been triggered):

[image: 0xc0000142]

But it works fine when it isn't needed. (i.e. exits with `Unable to abort the system shutdown because no shutdown was in progress.(1116)`) I'm running Windows 7x64

Comment: can you post the content of your batch file?

Comment: Just wondering why you would choose to put a shutdown abort command into a batch file?   FYI the help page does mention that the abort command will only work during the timeout period (set by /t N, where N=number of seconds to wait).   Is shutdown being called via another batch file?

Comment: `shutdown -s -t 3000`
`shutdown -a`